# Apple File system Permission to read from Photo Library

Tags: html, ios, xcode, uiwebview, ios10.3

I have a UIWebView inside my ios application , which loads responsive website into my webview, developed in asp.net . Website has a button to choose video from device Photo Library and another button to upload video.

In till ios version 10.2 it is uploading files successfully to server.
Apple introduce new version ios 10.3 with new file system APFS before it was HFS+ File System.
In ios 10.3 it doesnot allow my application to read video file and 0kb size is uploaded to server. This is because my app doesnot have read permission for that file.

How can I allow file system permission to read file from my app.Is there is anything that can be added to my info.plist

Do anyone stuck with this kind of issue.
Thanks

Comment: We are seeing the exact same problem with our iOS app that contains a UIWebView. All users that have upgraded their devices to iOS 10.3.1 and then try to upload an image or a video the file size of the image or video clip always becomes 0kb. We have made a temporary fix so uploading is being done in Safari instead until we can figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Yes , I Create a demo project in xcode 8.3 using ios 10.3 sdk . added a UIWebView and load google drive link into it. When uploading Image it was successful , but when i uploaded video it shows error message file unreachable

Comment: I haven't done any tests on WKWebView yet, but I have filed a bug report with Apple regarding UIWebView and hopefully the bug will be fixed as soon as possible since it affects all apps which need to upload files and uses the UIWebView, which is probably many thousands of apps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444430/cordova-ios-10-3-1-breaks-input-file-for-videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to a bug in UIWebView which makes all file input to have the multiple attribute set automatically.

The only solution for iOS 10.3 is to use WKWebView instead, which does not add the multiple attribute automatically.

It's mostly old iOS apps that use UIWebView which I guess is the reason why there are not many bug reports on the web related to this problem.

Comment: I replaced UIWebView with WKWebView , but it does not work , I also added NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent in WKWebView in info.plist, but no success